# Can degeneracy in the Hamiltonian spectrum be 'removed' using a symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, representation-theory

I have a quantum mechanical system with Hamiltonian, $H$. When I diagonalize $H$, the spectrum has degeneracy,

\begin{align}
H_\mathrm{diag} = \text{diag}(-1, -0.866, -0.866, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.866, 0.866, 1 )
\end{align}

I happen to be aware of a symmetry of $H$, given explicitly by a matrix $A$, for which $[H,A] = 0$. When I simultaneously block diagonalize $H$ and $A$, I find that $A$ has a block diagonal form, where the blocks of $A$ correspond with the degenerate eigenspaces of $H$. This is as expected, following from the fact that $[H,A] = 0$. Now I want to use this symmetry to *remove* the degeneracy in $H$. I want to work with a new matrix, call it $H'$, where the spectrum is the same, but the degeneracy is removed. I imagine it's spectrum would then look like,

\begin{align}
H_\mathrm{diag} = \text{diag}(-1, -0.866, 0, 0.866, 1 )
\end{align}

Is there some notion of *"quotienting by a symmetry"*, or some sort of projection into the lower dimensional subspace that doesn't have the degeneracy, that I can use? I think that this is somehow related to ideas presented in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/208009/195631), but I'm not looking to decompose $H$ into blocks, I'm wanting to work with an $H'$ that is non-degenerate, and of lower dimensionality.

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily remove parts of Hilbert space, that would be changing the model. What you could do is a separation of variables. For instance, in the usual spin decomposition, you have states $\vert s,m \rangle$, where the eigenvalue of certain Hamiltonians depend only $s$ and not on $m$. You can then simplify notation by writing $H \vert s\rangle = E_s \vert s \rangle$, and 'forget' about the $m$-subspace for each $s$-sector.

Comment: You want to *gauge* the symmetry associated with $A$. See the textbook *Quantization of Gauge Systems* by Marc Henneaux and Claudio Teitelboim, chapters 13-14 for a very general treatment.

Comment: @AronBeekman It appears you've  essentially answered the OP's question; writing it up as in illustrative answer with reference/analogy to hydrogen atoms would clarify it for him.

Comment: The Henneaux and Teitelboim reference looks like it might not be the most accessible for me. If anyone is aware of an existing reference/analogy to a simple system like hydrogen atoms, that would be most appreciated.